# Concatenate string with copy()

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

I'm new to C++ and I wonder is there a way to concatenate strings from `vector< string>` into one string using `copy()`. I know I can use `accumulate()`, but I wonder what's wrong "under the hood" with this code:

```
string concat_v (const vector<string>& v) {
  string s;
  copy(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(s));
  return s;
}
```

Or with:

```
s.insert(s.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code samples is that you can't copy a `string` to something that expects a `char`. It's the same problem as:

```
string s = "Hello";
char ch = s;         // ???
```

The `std::accumulate` function does exactly what you are requesting, I'm not sure why you are still wondering if there is a way :)  The way to use it is:

```
string s;
s = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), s);
```

which calls `operator+` to do the accumulation. There is also a version of accumulate which calls a custom function you provide.

Comment: He may not know how to use it (`operator+` versus binary version). I had to go look it up. (I learn lots of neat things from folks like you).

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to do the job with `std::copy` instead of `std::accumulate`, you could do so with a bit of an intermediary, such as `std::stringstream`:

```
string concat_v (const vector<string>& v) {
  stringstream s;
  copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(s));
  return s.str();
}
```

For this specific purpose, where all the inputs are of the same type and support the addition operator (and it does what you want), `accumulate` seems the clear choice. Using a stringstream might be preferable when/if you want a concatenated string, even if (for example) addition of the items might yield something entirely different (e.g., you want an array of int containing {1, 2, 3} to come out as `123` or `1 2 3`, not `6`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a one-liner, I'd use `accumulate`. I don't think there is a way with the two you mentioned.

```
string concat_v (const vector<string>& v) {
  string s;
  s = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), string());
  return s;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this will work as written.  `std::accumulate` uses the type of the third argument as an accumulator, and the type of `""`, when passed as an argument to a function template, is `char const*`.  I'd make the third argument `std::string()`.

Answer (score 0):

Going with std::accumulate brings a noticeable advantage in terms of performance.

In accumulate, we have

```
  while (first!=last) {
     init = init + *first;
     ++first;
  }
```

'init' is the resultant of the operation+ invocations and is accumulating the concatenated string. This is good, as it does not allocate temporaries for each intermediate result and neither does it copy. Of course, for string resizing you may have copies generated - but, that is a different matter.

The performance differential is non-trivial.